# Torsion-free subgroups in arbitrary lattices

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lattices, torsion

Let $\Gamma $ be a lattice in a semi-simple Lie group $G$. If the Lie group $G$ is linear (that is, it has a faithful finite-dimensional linear representation), then $\Gamma$ contains a torsion-free subgroup of finite index (Selberg's lemma). Is the same also true in case of an arbitrary (not necessarily linear) semi-simple Lie group $G$? This was an open problem some time ago. And now?

I am interested in examples of uniform lattices Γ in simply connected semi-simple Lie groups G that Γ have no torsion-free finite index subgroups. Are there any known examples of this type?

Comment: No, there are counterexamples due to Deligne (found in the late 70's) and then Raghunathan (who constructed cocompact examples), in finite covers of $\mathrm{Sp}_4(\mathbf{R})$. For references, see §5.8 p.26 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511714).

Comment: Many thanks. I forgot about this old Deligne's article

Comment: @YCor Deligne's result doesn't quite suit me. The finite coverings of the group $Sp_4 (\bf R)$ are not simply connected, and the lattices indicated there are nonuniform.

Here are the clarifications on my question.
  I am interested in examples of such uniform lattices $\Gamma$ in simply connected semi-simple Lie groups $G$ that $\Gamma$ have no torsion-free finite index subgroups. Are there any known examples of this type?

Comment: Deligne's example answers your question.If you want to modify the question, please edit it.

Comment: The Raghunathan examples are cocompact (=uniform) but it still happens that the fundamental group is infinite (the ambient group is $SO(2,n)$). So I'm not sure. For instance I don't know what can be said of inverses images of cocompact lattices of $SL_{n\ge 3}(\mathbf{R})$ in the (two-fold) universal covering.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for your answers and commentaries. An example with a two-sheeted cover over $SL_n(\bf R)$ would be very interesting. But, apparently, nobody knows anything about it now. I think that it is very interesting problem. I tried to solve it some years ago but to no avail.

Comment: I'm not aware of any redigest of the Deligne and Raghunathan examples. This is quite unfortunate, because this would be useful.